# How do I set this object's value? (Java 14)

Tags: java, class, oop, constructor

I am learning Java for the first time, and in the tutorial I am watching (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grEKMHGYyns), the instructor writes this code:

```
    private Name personName;

    public Person(Name personName){
        this.personName = personName;
    }
```

Does anyone know what the object 'personName' of the constructor class 'Name' does?

How would I be able to set a value to 'personName' using the constructor 'Name' of class 'Name'?

I would show you the code for 'Name,' but I don't know how to set it up so that the object of 'Name' would hold any value.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know how to call constructors and methods in java?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS To call a constructor in java you need to create a two classes, one with say, the name Car, and inside of that class, another method called Car as well. This is your constructor method, and whenever you call the class, or make an object of the class, it will be accessed, so you write code that every object of your class needs there. Calling a method of a class is much simpler, you just need to make a new object of the class, for example Car audi = new Car(empty parameters if you don't need any parameters for your constructor);, and then, you can access methods by Car.method().

Comment: I'm not a teacher testing you. There was absolutely no need for you to write that paragraph which I somehow doubt you didn't largely copy and paste. I was asking the question to better understand where your confusion lies and therefor be able to better answer. A simple yes/no was all i was looking for.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry, I thought that you were also new to Java and were asking me a question to learn something new. But yes, I do know how to call constructors and methods in Java. Sorry again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Name` can be anything really. I haven't watched the video (wow, it is long) but in this context I guess it could contain a `String` value for that person's name.

Based on the information given I assume the class could look like this:

```
public class Name {
    private final String name;

    public Name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then to instantiate your `Person`, you need an instance of `Name` first:

```
Name name = new Name("AnyName");
```

With that you can create a new `Person`:

```
Person person = new Person(name);
```

Comment: Good Answer. Might be a bit more useful to show `Name` as being more useful than a mere String, perhaps have two member fields: `givenName` and `surname` (known as first name and last name to Americans).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I noticed that with this new Name class, it kind of removes the need for the Person class to be there as well.